# google chart api draws negative axis as well though minValue is 0

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a google chart as follows which plots Age for various IDs. However, as age cannot be negative, I want it to be only on the positive axis.

I have given the minValue for vertical axis as 0, however it still shows the negative axis. How can I fix this?

My code below

```
function AgeChart() {
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

    var age_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    var divname = "agediv";

    age_data.addColumn('number', 'ID');
    age_data.addColumn('number', 'Age');


    age_data.addRow([1,10]);
    age_data.addRow([1,20]);
    age_data.addRow([1,30]);
    age_data.addRow([1,40]);
    age_data.addRow([1,50]);


    var options = {'title':'Age line graph',
        curveType: 'function',
        viewWindowMode:'explicit',
        vAxis: {title: 'Age (years)',
            minValue: 0,
        },
        hAxis: {title: 'ID'},
        height: 600,
        width: 1000
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(divname));
    chart.draw(age_data, options);
}
```

EDIT: After adding the viewWindow.min value, it works for me.

```
   function AgeChart() {
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

        var age_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        var divname = "agediv";

        age_data.addColumn('number', 'ID');
        age_data.addColumn('number', 'Age');


        age_data.addRow([1,10]);
        age_data.addRow([1,20]);
        age_data.addRow([1,30]);
        age_data.addRow([1,40]);
        age_data.addRow([1,50]);


        var options = {'title':'Age line graph',
            curveType: 'function',
            viewWindowMode:'explicit',
           vAxis: {title: 'Age (years)',
            minValue: 0,
            viewWindowMode:'explicit',
            viewWindowMode:'explicit',
            viewWindow:{
                min:0,
              }
            },
        hAxis: {title: 'ID'},
            height: 600,
            width: 1000
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(divname));
        chart.draw(age_data, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minValue and maxValue may be used to extend the axis to include those values, but they do not restrict the axis to those values.  What you want to do instead is use the viewWindow.min value.

Comment: I have made the change, please see my edit above. However, I don't notice any change in output.

Answer (score 3):

On the date 26/10/2015 the actual version of Google charts requires only the following to stop displaying the negatives on the vertical axis.

```
    var options = {
      hAxis: {  title: 'Dates',
            },
      vAxis: {  title: 'Count of something',
                viewWindow:{min:0},
            },
    };
```

As an option you can set up min value for more than 0 - it will give you same view.

```
      vAxis: {  title: 'Count',
                minValue: 2,                    
            },
```